Tabulator count cell-edits
I am trying to track edits in a Tabulator (6.3) table; for every edited cell, I want to highlight the cell with a certain color, but also the entire row of the edited cell with a less intense color.
Above the table I have a #save-btn which is only shown if there is at least 1 edited cell in the table.
When I have no edits, the #save-btn is hidden.
So I need to create an "edits" attribute (variable) to a row which holds the amount of edited cells on that row.
The #save-btn itself has an edits attribute which holds the count of edits of all cells in the table.
But how can I create an "edits" counter and fix it to the row?
I can add a class to an edited row using
cell.getRow().getElement().classList.add("edited-row");
But following did not work:
cell.getRow().createAttribute('edits') cell.getRow().hasAttribute('edits') cell.getRow().getAttribute('edits') = rowEdits+1;

Please go read [ask] and [mre]. You are really supposed to provide the latter, instead of just a few snippets of code that lack context, and a mere "doesn't work" as problem description.

I'm assuming what cell.getRow() gets you, isn't really referring to a DOM element - and therefor createAttribute & co. might not work on it? To access classList, you used cell.getRow().getElement() - what if you call the attribute related methods on that as well?

Hi @C3roe: you are right, this was the very first question I asked on Stackoverflow. Thanks for noticing, I coundn't quite make out the interface.

Also @C3roe: you are right;
'cell.getRow().getElement().setAttribute('edits', numOfEdits); '
solved it. Thanks!
